# Sort array of objects based on priority number

Tags: arrays, json, xml, sorting, object

I have a json file like:

```
"files": {
    "audio": {
        "number1": {
            "enabled": false,
            "priority": 5,
        },
        "number1": {
            "enabled": false,
            "priority": 1,
        },
        "number3": {
            "enabled": false,
            "priority": 2,
        }
    }
}


var audioMap = {
    'number1' : {‘name’:’Num1'},
    'number1' : {'name’:'Num2'},
    'number3' : {‘name’:'Num3'},
};
```

I convert this json file to xml with some function and also this function:

```
 function extractFile(data){

    var datas = [];
    var element = data.files.audio;


 for (number in audioFiles) {
        var audioName = audioMap[number].name;
        datas.push({
            name : audioName,
            value : audioFiles[number]. enabled ? "true" : "false",
        });
}

    return datas;
}
```

The output is:

```
   <file name="Num1" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num2" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num3" enabled="false”/>
```

How can I order them based on the priority number in the json?

The output needs to be like:

```
   <file name="Num2" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num3" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num1" enabled="false”/>
```

I do not know where to add sort and use “ priority” for sorting

For example if I want to use this function or any sort function:

```
function sortBy(key, reverse) {

var moveSmaller = reverse ? 1 : -1;

var moveLarger = reverse ? -1 : 1;

return function(a, b) {
if (a[key] < b[key]) {
  return moveSmaller;
}
if (a[key] > b[key]) {
  return moveLarger;
}
return 0;
};

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest getting the array of keys, sorting it, then mapping it to your output structure. The built-in sort function is sufficient, you just need to provide the comparison function.

A functional approach--

```
function extractFile(data) {
    return Object.keys(data.files.audio).sort(function(a,b) {
        return data.files.audio[a].priority - data.files.audio[b].priority;
    }).map(function(key) {
        return { name: audioMap[key].name,
                 value: data.files.audio[key].enabled ? "true" : "false" };
    });
}
```

If you need it to work in IE < 9 you can do the following:

```
function extractFile(data) {
    var keys = [];
    for (key in data.files.audio) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys.sort(function(a,b) {
        return data.files.audio[a].priority - data.files.audio[b].priority;
    }).map(function(key) {
        return { name: audioMap[key].name,
                 value: data.files.audio[key].enabled ? "true" : "false" };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but where is  datas.push({  how can I print my data?

Comment: datas.push just adds the argument to the datas array. This solution uses higher order functions to achieve the same result. You should be able to treat this function the same way as your version, except the output of this version will be sorted.

Comment: but I got an error (ReferenceError: objects is not defined)      for here   return Object.keys(data.files.audio).sort(function(a,b) {

Comment: did you capitalize Object?

Comment: I added a legacy browser compatible alternative that doesn't use Object.keys